# Fragments inside TabHost Activities

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am using a tabhost in my application with 3 tabs associated with 3 different activities. Inside each of the activities, I need to add a fragment(the fragment contains a video player which plays video from web). Below is the code of the activity which adds the fragment.

```
    public class FilmsActivity extends Activity {

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        private static final String TAG = "FilmsActivity";

        private static FragmentManager mFragmentManager;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Log.i(TAG, "Films onCreate ");
            mFragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            // get a video fragment. Title and URI as the constructor arguments
            VideoViewer vvFragment = VideoViewer.newInstance("Testing",Uri.parse("http://daily3gp.com/vids/747.3gp"));
            Log.i(TAG, "Films onCreate 1");
            VideoViewer vvFragment = VideoViewer.newInstance("Testing",Uri.parse("/sdcard/family_guy_test.3gp"));
            Log.i(TAG, "Films onCreate 2");
            fragmentTransaction.add(android.R.id.tabcontent, vvFragment, "videoFragment");
            Log.i(TAG, "Films onCreate 3");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    }
```

The fragment implementation is as shown below.

```
        public class VideoViewer extends Fragment {
        // Debug vars
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        private static final String TAG = "VideoViewer";
        private static final Boolean DBG_TOAST = false;
        private static final Boolean DBG_LOG = false;

        // Video Title, URL of the Video will be unique for each video. Save it in a member variable.
        private static final String VIDEO_TITLE = "title";
        private static final String VIDEO_URI = "uri";
        // Different states of the video viewer
        private static final int STATE_PAUSED = 0;
        private static final int STATE_PLAYING = 1;
        private static final int STATE_STOPPED = 2;
        // The view which holds the video player
        private VideoView mVideoView;
        // The transparent layout above the video which will be shown when it is paused and made not 
        // visible when the video is playing 
        // The title of the video is in the textview
        private TextView mVideoTitle;
        // UI Control Elements from the view.
        private ImageButton mPlayPauseButton;
        private Button mShareButton;
        private Button mAddToFavourites;
        // This holds the current state of the Video Viewer
        private int mVideoState;

        public static VideoViewer newInstance(String VideoTitle, Uri VideoUri) {
            VideoViewer VV = new VideoViewer();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            // Put the title and the uri in the bundle
            args.putString(VIDEO_TITLE, VideoTitle);
            args.putString(VIDEO_URI, VideoUri.toString());
            // Later on convert the string to Uri using uri.parse(string)
            return VV;
        }

        /* Return the view that is used by the fragment */
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Check if you want to use container or don't want to use anything
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_video_viewer, null);
        }

        /* Initialize the variables here, retrieve views and  */
        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            // Assignment for the local variables
            mVideoView = (VideoView) getView().findViewById(R.id.fragment_video_viewer_video);
            mVideoTitle = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.fragment_video_viewer_title);
            // Use the video title as the Text in the TextView
            mVideoTitle.setText(getArguments().getString(VIDEO_TITLE));
            // Get the URL from the argument bundle
            Uri videoUri = Uri.parse(getArguments().getString(VIDEO_URI));
            videoUri = Uri.parse("http://daily3gp.com/vids/747.3gp");
            // Toast if the URI is null
            if(DBG_TOAST) {
                if (videoUri.toString() == "") {
                    // Tell the user to provide a media file URL/path.
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Uri is null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    // Use a default video
                    // videoUri = Uri.parse("http://daily3gp.com/vids/747.3gp");
                }
            }
            // Initialize a media controller and anchor the videoview to it
            MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
            mediaController.setAnchorView(mVideoView);

            mVideoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
            mVideoView.requestFocus();
            mVideoView.setVideoURI(videoUri);
            mVideoView.start();
        }
    }
```

Can somebody tell me whats wrong with the implementation? An empty Films activity would produce a screen with 3 tabs as expected. However, when I try to run with this implementation, The app is not running at all.

The films activity is called from the mainactivity which creates a tabhost. So, the view for the films activity should go to `android.R.id.tabcontent`. should I use it when I add the fragment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the problem fixed. I had to extend `FragmentActivity` instead of `Activity`.